# Wondering if I'm doing this immutability exercise correctly

Tags: java, immutability

My professor just went over mutable and immutable, and gave us this coding exercise to complete.
1) Create a Customer object called customer with initial values of 1 and "Cust1" 
respectively.

2) Display the customer object to the screen using the toString() method.

3) Create a String object reference called name and assign to it the customer's name.

4) Assign the value "Bo Beep" to the object reference name.

5) Display the customer object to the screen using the toString() method.

The output should look like this.

Customer{id=1, name=Cust1}

Customer{id=1, name=Cust1}

I currently have 2 seperate classes, here they are. I'm not sure whether I'm doing it correctly, I think I have done the first 2 right, but I'm not sure about 3-5.

Any input is helpful, thanks!

Here's my main class,

```
package hw01;


public class Main {
static Customer customer = new Customer(1, "cust1");
static Customer name = new Customer(1, "Bo Peep");


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(customer);
    System.out.print(customer);

}
}
```

And here's my Customer class.

```
package hw01;

public class Customer {

private int id;
private String name;

public Customer() {
}

public Customer(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;


}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public  String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Customer{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + '}';
}

}
```

Comment: This seems like a _mutability_ exercise. In 4, shouldn't you be assigning the new value to the same object?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, and did I do 3 correctly? Could you explain 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like for #3 it should be something like this:

```
String name = customer.getName();
```

and then #4 would be:

```
name = "Bo Peep";
```

The goal of the exercise I think is to demonstrate that even though `name` and `customer.name` reference the same `String` object, since a `String` is immutable when you set `name = "Bo Peep";` you're not changing the actual `String` object but instead creating and referencing a new `String` object. If the `String` were mutable then printing the `customer` the 2nd time would display the name "Bo Peep".

Comment: Yes but did I set the name to Bo peep correctly? Also when it says to output using tostring, does that mean I have to call toString or just print(customer); ?

Comment: It's immutable because no setters and private variables correct?

Comment: Where would I put String name = customer.name; ?

Comment: I can't put it in my main class because of it being private in the other, and if I put it in the other it says it is already defined.

Comment: I think just printing the customer is fine because the `toString()` method is called implicitly.

Comment: You could use the getter, sorry. `String name = customer.getName();`

Comment: That's what I was thinking, where would it be placed in the class?

Comment: I would make each step of the exercise one line in the `main()` method.